# Default subject missing in the Jenkins email

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment, email-ext, jenkins-scriptler

I am adding recipients dynamically using the following in the pre-send script:

```
import javax.mail.Message
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress

msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress('recipient@example.com'))
```

Now after adding this the email subject is missing.

How to access the default subject line that Email ext plugin generates by default.

Comment: If this is indeed the case, please file an issue at https://issues.jenkins-ci.org so it can be debugged. Also, you probably want to add a line at the end of your script with just the word true

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding below line to your code

```
msg.setSubject("Subject");
```